# Storyboard: How to popover not full screen

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

Need a popover when pressed brightness button. Popover need to be NOT FULL-SIZED. I tried several setting but it always present as full-sized screen. What do you think I need to keep it 280x150px?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this may be an issue with default iOS popover behavior.  Popovers are only used for iPad / Regular Width size classes by default, and are full screen modals on iPhone / Conpact Width size classes.

This WWDC session covers that default behavior, and how to override it to have a popover presentation style on iPhone:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/214/.  (Skip to around 36:15)

Comment: Hi! Added an other screenshot, yes, I tried, to set `Preferred Content Size `.

Comment: @János Ohh... are you running this on iPad or iPhone?  Popover segues “adapt” to full screen modals by default on iPhone unless you write some code to change that behavior. Does this look like a small popover when you run it for iPad?

Comment: On iPhone, is it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see you in storyboard handled it as brigthness , you may in prepare wrote it brightness

Comment: `prepare(for segue` is not get called when pressing brightness button, why? VC just appears in fullscreen.

Comment: make sure the name of the seque u handle in prepare is brightness

Comment: No, handler is not get called at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create childViewController with UIView inside its view with proper constraint and UI element in it that u want to display as popUp.
2. Set background color of childViewController to default color.
3. Add segue from view (e.g button , on click of which you have to show childViewController as popup) to childViewController with type Present Modally with presentation "Over current context" and transition type as "Cross Dissolve".
4. Make sure you have added constraint to view inside childViewController view properly so it will display at correct position as popUp.